# ng-animate does not seem to work

Tags: angularjs

I an trying to follow the example in the angularjs website to do animations, so here is my css (stylus):

```
.animate-enter-setup
  -webkit-transition 1s linear all
  -moz-transition    1s linear all
  -ms-transition     1s linear all 
  -o-transition      1s linear all 
  transition         1s linear all
  opacity            0

.animate-enter-setup.animate-enter-start
  opacity            1
```

and in my jade template:

```
ul
  li.row.spacing-small(ng-repeat='item in items', ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter'}")
    p {{item}}
```

I fail to see why this is not working. Any help?

Comment: which angular version do you use?

Comment: When do you want these items to animate? When they load, on some event?